# Is there a way to provide a custom sort function in jqGrid 3.7.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jQuery Grid 3.7.2 to load data in 'loadonce' mode, i.e. jqGrid takes care of sorting locally once the data has loaded.  One column has a string value that uses a custom formatter, and also requires custom sorting.

Unfortunately it seems that providing a function as the 'sorttype' in the column model is not available until jqGrid 3.8.0.  Sadly, 3.8.0 has various crippling bugs, and the recently-released 3.8.1 not only fails to fix them, but also breaks column reordering.  So I'm stuck on 3.7.2 for the time being.

Short of translating my values to integers on the server side, is there anything I can do to get custom sorting in 3.7.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after it having gone answer-less for a month, I don't believe this is possible.  I ended up translating the values to integers on the server side, to ensure their ability to sort, then provided a custom grid formatter to transform them back when displayed to the user.